# My Sprite Shape profiler is not working correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-development

I am currently making a game replica for practising game development, but while trying to make a close sprite shape, I encountered this problem. I think I did everything right but I don't know why is it not working. It should make the thin road on the top of the sprite.[Talking about PNG]

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]I
[image: Image 3]

I tried to fix the angle but when I do it more than 90 degrees, the whole sprite gets the road design.